# jQuery on submit issue

Tags: php, jquery

For some reason my submit event is not working, however, if i change it to click on the form, it works, this is my code:

**JQUERY:**

```
 <script>
(function(){
        $('form').on('click',function(){

                $.post("../includes/register.php",  $('form').serialize(),
                function(data){
                    $('body').append(data);                 
                });
        });
    })();
</script>
```

**REGISTER.PHP:**

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['username'])){
echo $_POST['username'];
}
?>
```

This works perfectly fine, it appends the username whenever I click on a form text input, however, when I try to use the submit method, it doesnt output anything:

```
<script>
(function(){
        $('form').submit(function(){

                $.post("../includes/register.php",   $('form').serialize(),
                function(data){
                    $('body').append(data);                 
                });
        });
    })();
</script>
```

As a matter of fact, it doesn't even work when I use button.on('click')

Comment: What does the HTML for the submit button look like, and you probably have to return false or prevent the default submit action inside the handler for the submit event.

Comment: It seems you want to use document ready handler instead of an immediately invoked function!

Comment: or use preventDefault directly

Answer (score 1):

You are using an immediately invoked function instead of document ready handler, also you should prevent the default action of the event, try the following:

```
$(function(){
    $('form').on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post("../includes/register.php",  $(this).serialize(),
        function(data){
            $('body').append(data);                 
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The form will submit to the form's action by default.  You need to prevent this from happening.  You are waiting for a server response via ajax, so it is most likely you will never witness your callback executing before the default action occurs.

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); // put this first
            $.post("../includes/register.php",   $('form').serialize(),
            function(data){
                $('body').append(data);                 
            });
    });
```

Comment: i think `e.stopPropagation()` is the better solution

Comment: @Philipp - That just stops bubbling, not the default action, which is required here.

Comment: you still could return false

Comment: return false won't return if some code bugs inside function, while preventDefault() is ran before anything can go wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is speculation right now since I do not know what your HTML code looks like.

But on submit the form will be submitted, and any active ajax requests will be cancelled. 
Try something like

```
<script>
(function(){
   $('form').submit(function(){    
     $.post("../includes/register.php",   $('form').serialize(),
       function(data){
         $('body').append(data);                 
     });
     return false;
   });
  })();
</script>
```

That will stop the submit event and you should get the post event to occur. Though it will NOT actually submit the form. So you'll have to do that manually.